# why this python function return len=7 instead of len=6?

Tags: python-3.x

I got this code below, but even debugging it, I cannot understand why gives me out 7 instead of 6.

More precisely when I debudg every return gives me the expected result:

1. first func call: `ipdb> --Return-- ['a']`
2. second func call: `ipdb> --Return-- ['a', 'a']`
3. third func call: `ipdb> --Return-- ['a', 'a', 'a']`

but at the end `func() + func() + func()` becomes `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`

why is there one 'a' more???

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def func(par=[]):
    par.append("a")
    return par

print(len(func() + func() + func()))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When executing `func() + func() + func()`, Python has to store the temporary objects on the stack to add them together, it means that your code is equivalent to

```py
a = func() # returns ['a']
b = func() # returns ['a', 'a'], but variable 'a' now holds ['a', 'a'] as well!
tmp = a + b
c = func() # return ['a', 'a', 'a']
d = tmp + c
return d
```

Because of the Mutable Default Argument, before actually adding `a+b`, both `a` and `b` are equal to `['a', 'a']`, giving you `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`, 4 elements, then you add `['a','a','a']` you got from the 3rd `func()` call, and you get 7 elements as a result.

Comment: you must corrent tmp=x+y to tmp=a+b; but for the rest you are a genius :)